# Apparent contradiction between expectation of the product of random variables and law of total expectation

Tags: random-variable, expected-value

Suppose we have two random variables $X, Y$. Then, in general, if they are dependent $$E[XY] \ne E[X]E[Y]$$

However, according to the law of total expectation, $$E[XY] = E_Y[E_X[XY|Y]] = E_Y[YE[X]]=E[Y]E[X].$$ Furthermore, this law doesn't stipulate that $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

How can we reconcile this?

Comment: Ah that makes sense, if you make it an answer I can accept it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [law of total expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation) states that
$$\mathbb 
E_X[X]=\mathbb E_Y[\mathbb E_{X|Y}[X|Y]]
$$
Introducing $Y$ leads to
$$\mathbb 
E_{(X,Y)}[YX]=\mathbb E_Y[\mathbb E_{X|Y}[XY|Y]]
= \mathbb E_Y[Y\mathbb E_{X|Y}[X|Y]]
$$
which differs from $\mathbb E_Y[Y]\mathbb E_{X}[X]$ when $\mathbb E_{X|Y}[X|Y]$ depends on $Y$.

Comment: Why is the first expectation $\mathbb{E}_X[YX]$ only over $X$?

Comment: @Kuku: a typo, it is. And there was another one, with the $XY$ in the subscript rather than the integrand. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for correcting. I am confused though still, shouldn't the second term have $XY|Y$ as subscript instead of $X|Y$?

Comment: No, although it does not make a difference in the end.